# How to get all the metrics associated with a list of resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to get the list of metrics from CloudWatch for a list of resources.

I tried sending params as follows to the

```html
var dimensions = [{
        "Name": "FunctionName",
        "Value": "Dummy"
      },{
         "Name": "FunctionName",
        "Value": "Dumy1"
      }];
      var params = {
        Namespace: "AWS/Lambda",
        "Dimensions": dimensions
      };
```

```html
cloudwatch.listMetrics(params, function(err, CloudData) {
});
```

But the service takes the dimensions as a combination and uses both the values in dimensions to filter. 
I don't want that to happen.
Is there anyway to do that other than making a service call for each resource separately.

Answer (score 0):

When you request metrics for multiple dimensions, the dimensions are handled using an AND combination. So it returns metrics where all dimensions applies.

You're looking for an OR combination. In this case, you must call `listMetrics` separately, once for each dimension.

Comment: Yeah. I have no other option.